# Filter rows with list of strings and NaN altogether in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter the rows having strings and NaN values.
The following code does not work

```
   list=['ok','good','fine']
    
   df_new = df[(df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(list))) | (df.b.isnull())]
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan, 4, 3 ], 'b':['ok',1,np.nan, np.nan,'fine' ]})
df

        a   b
   0    1.0 ok
   1    2.0 1
   2    NaN NaN
   3    4.0 NaN
   4    3.0 fine

df[(df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(list))) | (df.b.isnull())]

        a   b
   0    1.0 ok
   4    3.0 fine
```

**Desired Output**

```
   0    1.0 ok
   2    NaN NaN
   3    4.0 NaN
   4    3.0 fine
```

I know there are many way to achieve this but wondering why this code is not working

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: `df[df.b.isnull() | df.b.str.contains('|'.join(l))]` works fine.

Comment: Quite weird.  How does this differ from OP's command?

Comment: @MayankPorwal boolean-logic shortcutting. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(l))` produces `NaN`s, since a comparison to `NaN` here will yield a `NaN` in the result. That is,

```
>>> df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(l))
0    True
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4    True
```

If you logical-or(*) that with the `df.b.isnull()` condition, the `NaN`s will be interpreted as `False` (or probably as `NaN` even, but be equivalent to `False`):

```
>>> df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(l)) | df.b.isnull()
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
```

Hence you lose a few rows.

If you reverse the order for the logical-or, shortcutting for comparisons will kick in: if sides are or-ed, and the left-hand side is `True`, there is no need to look at the right-hand side (whether it be `False`, `True` or `NaN`), and thus your rows remain:

```
>>> df.b.isnull() | df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(l))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
```

Hence you'll get your result when you logical-or the sides in reverse order:

```
>>> df[df.b.isnull() | df.b.str.contains('|'.join(l))]
     a     b
0  1.0    ok
2  NaN   NaN
3  4.0   NaN
4  3.0  fine
```

(You can remove some parentheses, as well as replace the `['b']` part.)

---

I don't think this is something to rely on, though. You would be better off, for example, by replacing the `NaN`s with a more relevant value (perhaps an empty string), so that the boolean combination works both ways. Because at some point, a trick like the one above, will bite you.

```
df.b = df.b.fillna("")
```

replaces the `NaN`s with an empty string.

---

(*) "logical-or" is not a verb that I know of, but for this context, I made it a verb. As some say: verbing weirds language.